# Flux personal store for component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have UI like this:

```
First User: <UserSelect value={this.state.user1} />
Second User: <UserSelect value={this.state.user2} />
...
Other User: <UserSelect value={this.state.user3} />
```

Where `UserSelect` is component for selecting user with autocomplete. There can be many of them. One type of component can listen singleton Store in Flux. But in my case the change of value in one `UserSelect` component affects the states of the others.

How should I build my app to solve this problem?

Create one store per component in `componentDidMount`?

```
// not flux way
componenDidMount: function() {
  this.usersStore = UsersStore.createStore();
  this.usersStore.on('change', ...);
}
```

Or making something like query selectors in Store?

```
// flux way, but affects all mounted components on page
componenDidMount: function() {
  UsersStore.on('change', this.update);
},

update: function() {
  this.setState({
    items: UserStore.get({ loginLike: this.state.inputValue })
  });
},

handleInputChange: function(e) {
  this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  loadUsersAction({ loginLike: e.target.value });
}
```

Or ...?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the second approach and do something like query selectors and be fine. Just don't forget about the correct Flux flow.

If you want to have really great performance and easier development in long-run, use immutable data structures. Then, you will not have to worry about affecting other components (regarding to the performance). Here is a simple introduction article: http://blog.risingstack.com/the-react-js-way-flux-architecture-with-immutable-js/

Comment: Thank you for links. But I sltil don't like that components have unnecessary  subscribtions and callings.